# Check if two lines start with the same character, if so the output average, if not, print actual value

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'd like to check if two rows start with the same number in the 1st column, if that happens, then the average of the 2nd column should be displayed. File example:

```
01  21    6    10%       93.3333%
01  22    50   83.3333%  93.3333%
02  20.5  23   18.1102%  96.8504%
02  21.5  100  78.7402%  96.8504%
03  22.2  0    0%        100%
03  21.2  29   100%      100%
04  22.5  1    5.55556%  100%
04  23.5  17   94.4444%  100%
05  22.7  9    7.82609%  100%
05  21.7  106  92.1739%  100%
06  23    11   17.4603%  96.8254%
06  22    50   79.3651%  96.8254%
07  20.5  14   18.6667%  96%
07  21.5  58   77.3333%  96%
08  21.8  4    100%      100%
09  22.6  0    0%        100%
09  21.6  22   100%      100%
```

For instance, the two first lines start with `01`, but there is only one line starting with `08` (15th line). Therefore, the output based on these two cases should be:

```
01 21.5
...
...
...
08 21.8
...
...
...
```

I ended up with the following awk line, which works great when the file always has two similar lines, but it fails using the file shown above (because the 15th line):

```
awk '{sum+=$2} (NR%2)==0{print sum/2; sum=0;}'
```

Any hint is welcomed,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This awk should work:

```
awk 'function dump(){if (n>0) printf "%s%s%.2f\n", p, OFS, sum/n}
     NR>1 && $1 != p{dump(); sum=n=0} {p=$1; sum+=$2; n++} END{dump()}' file
01 21.5
02 21.0
03 21.7
04 23.0
05 22.2
06 22.5
07 21.0
08 21.8
09 22.1
```

**Explanation:** We are using 3 variables:

```
p -> to hold previous row's $1 value
n -> count of similar $1 values
sum -> is sum of $2 values for similar $1 rows
```

**How it works:**

```
NR>1 && $1 != p     # when row #1 > 1 and prev $1 is not current $1
dump()              # function is to print formatted value of $1 and average
p=$1; sum+=$2; n++  # sets p to $1, adds current $2 to sum and increments n
```

Comment: That will core dump on an empty file.

Comment: @EdMorton I'd be interested in some more info about this possibility EdMorton, thanks for pointing this.

Comment: @anubhava thanks for your answer, would you please explain how it works? thanks again!

Comment: @Gery If the file's empty, the END section will still get executed but the `n` variable will have value zero, so the `sum/n` in the function will be a divide-by-zero. You never want to see an unguarded `print` in an `END` section because that means the script will attempt to print something even when the file is empty and then either a) you get something (often nonsense, but sometimes very misleading) printed which is undesirable, or b) you get a core dump or some other significant error.

Comment: @Gery: I've added a check to take care of empty variable and have added explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU awk

```
gawk '
    {sum[$1]+=$2; n[$1]++} 
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        for (key in sum) print key, sum[key]/n[key]
    }
' file
```

```
01 21.5
02 21
03 21.7
04 23
05 22.2
06 22.5
07 21
08 21.8
09 22.1
```

The "PROCINFO" line makes the array traversal sorted my index numerically. Otherwise the output would appear random.

Comment: This solves also the question when the input is unsorted or when some number appeurs more than twice. The question is not really clear what should happen when the first number shows up a third time, this seems the desired solution.

Comment: @WalterA thanks for pointing that, but in my case I get no more than two similar values in the first column, but very likely several "unique" rows. I think I need more testing to re-choose the right answer.

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for your answer, it'd be great some more info about how it works, thanks again!

Comment: @Gery yes, when you ask a question it's a good idea to wait more than 15 mins or so to select an answer as that discourages others from posting alternatives which might be in some ways better than the first answer posted. Remember - a solution that produces the output you want given some specific sample input you posted is just the first step towards selecting a solution you want to adopt!

Comment: @Gery, I think it's pretty self-evident. Do you have any specific questions?

Answer (score 1):

awk with piped sort

```
awk '{s[$1]+=$2;c[$1]++} END{for(i in s) print i, s[i]/c[i]}' file | sort
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this one is shorter than the other ones, would you mind to explain it please? thanks!

Comment: sum the values indexed by field 1 (key) and keep track of counts in arrays s(um) and c(ount); when all records are done (END block) print the key and the average for all keys.  The array hashing shuffles the order of elements but since you have the natural ordering the sort will fix that.

Comment: @Gery - it is shorter because the awk command uses single-character instead of multi-character variable names, stores every `$1` in memory twice and will produce the output in a different order than it was input, hence the need for an additional pipe and sort.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
second{
    if($1 == first){
        print (second + $2) / 2
        second = 0
        next
    }
    else
        print second
}
{
    printf "%s ", $1
    fist = $1
    second = $2
}
END{
    if(second)
        print second
}' file
```